# how can i code social media icon in html using bootstrap4

Tags: bootstrap-4

am new to web development, am having issue in writing facebook icon on my html,

```
<div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center padding">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h1>connect</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 social padding">
      <a href=""><i class="fab fa-facebook-f">facebook</i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i tried this but is not working

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If you're using the font awesome library, make sure you include their dependencies in your HTML file

Answer (score 0):

The icon you are trying to add i.e. `<i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>` is a Font Awesome Icon.
It won't work unless you add a link to the font awesome icons library.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1ycn6IcaQQ40/MKBW2W4Rhis/DbILU74C1vSrLJxCq57o941Ym01SwNsOMqvEBFlcgUa6xLiPY/NS5R+E6ztJQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```

Add the above link tag in the `<head>` of your html file and the icon should show.